# Xcode How to disable + and Edit button for UITableview

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have a Xcode project that is based on a `UITableView`. I used the `UITableViewController`, and I have my cells all setup. Now I want to remove the "+" and "Edit" Buttons on the application. I have managed to remove editing to the cells but still the "Edit" and "+" buttons are there. This causes the app to crash if the "+" button is tapped.

How do I solve this?

Comment: you can do this very fast, in UItableViewController viewDidLoad, self.navigationItem.rightButtonItem = nil

Comment: Or in viewDidLoad, self.navigationItem.rightButtonItem.enabled = NO;

Comment: @user3296713 - + and Edit button are on the Navigation bar ????

Comment: If there are + and Edit buttons they are there because they are somewhere added in your code, or they exist in the storyboard that is used to create the viewController. They don't come out of nowhere, so find where they are added and remove them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable the editing mode for the table view.

```
[self.tableView setEditing:NO];
```